# Oracle: select with date range filter throws invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, formatting

```
Select
    *
from
    view
where
    datecolumn = to_date('2019-02-26 12:11:23','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

returns records but

```
Select
    *
from
    view
where
    datecolumn > to_date('2019-02-26 12:11:23','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

throws invalid number error.

But not always only fails for few dates.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I almost feel like maybe the `datecolumn` is somehow the problem.  Is that a date column, or is it text?

Comment: Yes It is a date data type column with values like this:
 2/27/2019 2:54:24 PM
2/27/2019 9:30:08 AM

Comment: Is `datecolumn` text or is it a date?

Comment: Yes It is a date data type column.

Comment: @NirmalAzhagarselvam Is `table` really a view that created the date column based on a string?  With that error message there has to be a type conversion going on somewhere.

Comment: @JonHeller Yes it is a view and I do not have much idea on the source table/View. but no formatting done for this column from base table/view.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the issue with a different column where it is converted to a number data type. I have reported it to source team to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of column *datecolumn* ?

I guess your table column datecolumn is varchar type and having date stored in different format.

Comment: No the column is a date datatype column and values are stored in date format

Comment: Convert the table column also to_date(datecolumn ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and try once

Answer (score 0):

As JonHeller said the issue is with type conversion went wrong in some other column.